C++ happens-before relationship and memory_order_consume
Consider the following example of using std::memory_order_consume to synchronize data:
struct X
{
    int i;
    std::string s;
};

std::atomic<X*> p;
std::atomic<int> a;

void create_x()
{
    X* x=new X;
    x->i=42;
    x->s="hello";
    a.store(99,std::memory_order_relaxed);                     //1
    p.store(x,std::memory_order_release);                      //2
}

void use_x()
{
    X* x;
    while(!(x=p.load(std::memory_order_consume)))              //3
        std::this_thread::sleep(std::chrono::microseconds(1));

    assert(x->i==42);                                          //4
    assert(x->s=="hello");                                    // 5

    assert(a.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)==99);            // 6
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(create_x);
    std::thread t2(use_x);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}

Anthony Williams in his book "Concurrency in Action" gives the following explanation:

Even though the store to a 1 is sequenced before the store to p 2, and
the store to p is tagged memory_order_release, the load of p 3 is
tagged memory_order_consume. This means that the store to p only
happens before those expressions that are dependent on the value
loaded from p. This means that the asserts on the data members of the
X structure (4 and 5) are guaranteed not to fire, because the load of
p carries a dependency to those expressions through the variable x. On
the other hand, the assert on the value of a 6 may or may not fire;
this operation isn’t dependent on the value loaded from p, and so
there’s no guarantee on the value that’s read. This is particularly
apparent because it’s tagged with memory_order_relaxed.

This explanation makes sense, but when I try to think about it in terms of happens-before relationships as defined by cppreference, I am failing to conclude the same:

There is a sequenced-before and happens-before relationship between the stores 1 and 2
There is a dependency-ordered-before and inter-thread-happens-before relationship between 2 and 3
Since inter-thread-happens-before relationship combines with sequenced-before relationship, the store 1 inter-thread-happens-before the load 3, and, consequently, 1 happens-before 3
The load 3 is sequenced-before the load 6 by the program order, therefore 3 happens-before 6
As we have concluded, 1 happens-before 3 and 3 happens-before 6, then by transitivity 1 happens-before 6

The last statement seems to contradict what is written in the book. Is there a mistake in my logical chain or the fact that the store 1 happens-before the load 6 does not necessarily mean that the effects of 1 are visible to 6?

release/consume doesn't "synchronize-with", it has special wording in the ISO standard to describe how only things that are data-dependent on the load(consume) result are guaranteed to see the values you want.  Memory order consume usage in C11 discussed the standardese in comments.  (And my answer there discusses the point of dependency-ordering for memory and how it's weaker than acquire.  Also C++11: the difference between memory_order_relaxed and memory_order_consume)

@PeterCordes Re: "All CPUs (except DEC Alpha AXP's famously weak memory model) do it for free, unlike acquire. (Except on x86 and SPARC-TSO, where the hardware has acq/rel memory ordering without extra barriers or special instructions.)" - Does the second "except" mean that x86 and SPARC-TSO do acquire for free? This is a topic I have very little knowledge about and I got stuck on that part. Would it be possible to rephrase it in a way that is easier for curious non-pros to digest?

I believe memory_order_consume will be removed in C++26

Keep in mind that cppreference is not itself the standard.  It's an attempt by independent third-party contributors to explain the standard in a way that's more accessible to working programmers.  On the whole they do a very good job, but occasionally mistakes do creep in, especially in subtle areas such as the memory model.  So when in doubt, it's always best to refer to the standard itself.  In this instance, though, I think they simply quote the standard, and quote it correctly.

@TedLyngmo: For x86, yes, acquire is free - or perhaps we should say more precisely, you pay for it whether you want it or not.  Every load instruction has acquire semantics; there's no instruction to perform a "relaxed load" that can be reordered with later loads and stores, even if you might wish there were in order to get a speedup.  Likewise, every store has release semantics.  I'm not familiar with SPARC-TSO but I presume Peter is saying the same is true there.

@LWimsey: I'm curious where you heard that.  It's still in the latest C++26 draft I found (N4981).

@TedLyngmo: Adding to Nate's reply, x86's memory model is program-order plus a store-buffer with store-forwarding, like what in-order 486 did naturally without hit-under-miss caches etc.  So there's StoreLoad reordering, but not LoadLoad or StoreStore or LoadStore.  That's acq/rel: https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/.  (And reloading your own stores lets you see them before they're globally visible; that's the store-buffer effect.  That's compatible with acq_rel but not seq_cst.)

@NateEldredge: I don't know a lot about SPARC, but apparently they started using a total-store-order memory model in later versions, similar to x86's TSO memory model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_consistency#Similarity_to_SPARC_V8_TSO,_IBM-370,_and_x86-TSO_memory_models  / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering#Runtime_memory_ordering - oh, apparently there's a RISC-V extension for TSO as well.  Which would be useful for emulating x86, like Apple M1 where that's a mode that can be enabled/disabled.

@NateEldredge I read it in Herb Sutter's trip report about the C++ standards meeting in Poland

@LWimsey: Interesting read, thank you.

Your logical error is in the last step.  The definition of happens-before in C++23 (N4950 final draft) is:

An evaluation A happens before an evaluation B (or, equivalently, B
happens after A) if:
— A is sequenced before B, or
— A inter-thread
happens before B.

Notice there is not a third clause saying "if A happens before X and X happens before B".  The happens-before relation is not defined as transitive.
So it's true that 1 happens before 3 and 3 happens before 6, but it does not follow that 1 happens before 6.
Notice too that you cannot show that 1 inter-thread happens before 6.
(When there are no consume operations, so that no operation is dependency-ordered before any other, then you can show that happens-before is transitive, and is the transitive closure of the union of sequenced-before and synchronizes-with.  This matches how simply-happens-before is defined, and there is a note pointing this out.)
